# href target tab should open a tab in first and update on second time

Tags: javascript, html

I am quite new to HTML, I have senior where I have two anchor tags in one HTML page.

Example:Main.html

```
<a href ="https://www.google.co.in/" target="_blank">Google</a><br>
<a href ="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">facebook</a>
```

My goal is to open Facebook or Google in a new tab when the user first clicks a link.

When the user clicks a link again, it shouldn't open a new tab, but instead it should update the Google or Facebook tab that has already been opened.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set your `target` attribute.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="facebookTargetTab" />Facebook</a>
```

Links with the same `target` will open up in the same new tab.  This behavior is a holdover from the days of framesets, where each frame was named.  If the name didn't exist, a new window (and these days, a new tab) was opened.

Comment: Thanks Brad for the response 

Below are my anchor tags

<a href ="https://www.google.co.in/" target="blank">Google</a><br>

<a href ="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">facebook</a>

perblom here is Google anchor tag is working as required

But Facebood anchor tag is keep on opening in next tab and if I replace traget with blank it is overding the Google tab only

So I need Google to open first time and next time on click of Google it should redirect me the Google tab that was alread open not in new tab or facebook tab(if it is opened)

Same for Facbook also

Comment: @PritiranjanSwain Yeah, stop using `_blank`.  Follow the example and read the answer I wrote for you.  `_blank` has special meaning.  For regular target names, if you use the same target value, you'll end up opening links into the same tab.

Comment: Thanks Brad its working as per expectation..you save my day